# What is the term for swapping parts in a harmony?

Tags: theory, harmony, terminology, voice-leading

What is the technical term given to the technique where parts of a choir switch or swap their parts in a harmony?

Comment: You're probably thinking of [voice crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_crossing)

Comment: The question is too loose for a meaningful answer.   You could be talking about voice-crossing, imitation, repeating the same chord in a different inversion....    A music example of what you mean would help.

Comment: Given the two very good answers from Richard and Laurence, I think you need to explain at bit, especially in regard to the octave of the voices.

Answer (score 5):

You may be looking for the term **voice exchange**.

A voice exchange occurs when the pitches being sung or played by two parts are switched. For example, if a bass is singing a C while a soprano sings an E, if suddenly the bass switches to an E and the soprano switches to a C, we say there has been a voice exchange between the soprano and bass.

Note, also, that there can be intervening chords that serve to prolong the voice exchange.

For a notated example, jjmusicnotes incorporated a terrific image in their answer to [Voice-leading with three chords in first inversion?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/17802/21766):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this sort of thing?  Repeating the same notes, but adding some movement?   Not uncommon in instrumental writing, but singers could do it.

It's not really 'hocketing'.  In  Schenkerian analysis it might be called 'voice exchange'.    I'd just describe it in plain English - 'swapping notes'.

If you mean something else, an example would help.

[image]